# Use of Or/And combination conditions in the task query in Camunda 7

Tags: camunda

**I need to implement this logic in the taskQuery to pull out a task list:**

pull up those tasks which meets one of these conditions :

- either assigned to this user
- or that task is unassigned but belongs to the group that user is part of (based on role )

**With the above logic, I tried :**

```
taskQuery
  .taskUnassigned().taskCandidateGroupIn(group)
  .or().taskAssignee(assignee).endOr()
.list();
```

**My list is always empty with the above query. However, if I try separately :**

- taskQuery.taskUnassigned().taskCandidateGroupIn(groups) ----> pulls
  out right tasks in the list
- taskQry.taskAssignee(assignee) —> pulls out right tasks in the list

**Question:**

- What am I doing wrong in my combined query when using the OR condition?
- Is there a way to implement “AND” condition so that I can do something like :

Example:

```
  taskQuery
    .or()
      and().taskUnassigned().taskCandidateGroupIn(group).endAnd()
    .endOr()
    .or()taskAssignee(assignee).endOr()
  .list();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I couldn't get that to work either and just do 2 requests (tested with postman)... you can try to ask in the forum, sometimes you get lucky.